# Neo4j 3 - graph style sheet (.grass) on the server? global for all users

Tags: neo4j

I would like to set a .grass so that any (and all) of my db users see the same styling.
(I know i can do it locally, but im looking for a global way)
The default style sheet must be stored somewhere on the server, but I can't seem to locate it.

Answer (score 1):

Browser configuration is store on your browser into a localstorage. So there is nothing on the server.

With the 3.0 there is a new feature : browser-sync.
Now, you can save your configuration in the cloud with a github or twitter or google user.

So a hack will be to create a fake user, save your data into the cloud with this user, and share the login/password with everyone.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can make your own build of [`neo4j-browser`](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser), in which there are other default styles:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/blob/master/app/scripts/services/GraphStyle.coffee

2) Dirty "hack": you can only rebuild the `javascript` script and replace it directly in the jar-file:

```
{neo4j-dir}/lib/neo4j-browser-*.jar/browser/scripts/*.scripts.js
```

3) Another possible dirty "hack": add modified `GraphStyle.js` at the end of `{neo4j-dir}/lib/neo4j-browser-*.jar/browser/index.html`